# Play random video from a directory

Tags: javascript, php, video, random, mediaelement.js

I am a newbie in javascript, and I want a video player (resize-able) to play randomly my videos that are located in a directory on the server.

I know about `Math.random` but I don't know how to play a video based on the results generated by `Math.random`.

Any help is more than welcome.

Comment: How are videos named?

Comment: So, you want us to tell you how to get an array of the videos (presumably with php), how to generate a random number within the confines of that array, how to then load that video and start it playing (using JavaScript?)? Have you made any attempts at all to research any individual step? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: This could have had an interesting answer if the questions would have been asked properly with some code. What I would do is to list all the video names (including their absolute paths) in a txt file. Then I would write a little php script that randomly returns one video out of the txt file into a `src` attribute of a `<video>` tag for instance (with no javascript involved) PS. you are misunderstanding how `Math.random` works

Comment: can you give me an example or tell me where to look for?

Answer (score 2):

You can use php´s scandir http://php.net/manual/de/function.scandir.php

you pass it the path where youre videos are and it will return an array of all containing files ( and directorys, but be sure to only have files there)

```
$files = scandir ( "/videos/");

$randomFile = $files[array_rand($files)];
```

so now you have the filename in $randomFile and you can pass it wherever you need it:
some pseudo js-videoplayer-code :

```
 $.playVideo({ 
   "source": "/videos/" + <?php echo $randomfile ?>
 });
```

Comment: so the complete php code will be something like :
<? php
$files = scandir ( "/videos/");

$randomFile = $files[array_rand($files)];
?>
, right??

Comment: yes it will be something like code

Comment: I will try it out
thanks!
and I will just call the source like you said in pseudo code, correct?
I have to put them all in a html file to see if it is working 
thanks again!

Comment: well this depends on what videoplayer you use, what i wanted to express is that you have the fileName of a random video ind that php variable and you can echo it whereever you need it, i´m sure somewhere your videoplayer expects a path to the video it will play

Comment: so is there a way to have a fixed path for the video file and a php script picks a random file copies it to that location?

you know what i mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to address the confusion regarding how to utilize the random number that you generate:

What you'll want to do is have all of your files in an array and then the random number you generate should be between 0 and the length of your array (ie: the total number of video files).

The random number will be an index in the array and hence a random selection.

For example, if you have 10 file names in the array and your random number is 4, you extract the element at index 4 of your array.